# mysql how to restore data for part of a table

Tags: mysql, database-restore

Let's say I have table A, it has 3000 rows and I know the first 2000 rows are corrupt and I have a clean records sitting in another mysql server. What would be the easiest way to restore that 2000 rows? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Maatkit's](http://www.maatkit.org/) [mk-table-checksum](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-checksum.html) tool you can determine the differences between the tables of two hosts.

[mk-table-sync](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-sync.html) is used to generate and/or run only the statements necessary to update the corrupted table.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to copy the mysql file from the backup server and delete the file on the production server.